# How to prove that $B$ is positive definite when $\|A-B\|\leq\lambda_\min(A)$ for some positive definite $A$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Denote by $\mathbb R^{n \times n}$ the vector space of $n \times n$ matrices with real entries.
For $A \in \mathbb R^{n \times n}$, the notation $A\succ 0$ means that $A$ is symmetric and positive definite.

Question:

Suppose $A,B \in \mathbb R^{n \times n}$ are such that $A\succ0,\, B=B^T$ and that $\|A-B\|\leq\lambda_\min(A)$, where $\lambda_\min(A)$ is the smallest eigenvalue of $A$. Prove that $B\succ0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** it suffices to show that the lowest eigenvalue of $A - B$ is positive.  Note that for a symmetric matrix $M$, the lowest eigenvalue can be expressed as
$$
\lambda_{min}(M) = \min_{\|x\| = 1} x^TMx
$$
and that
$$
\|M\| = \max_{\|x\| = 1} \left|x^TMx \right|
$$

---

I've combined several ideas to get that last equality.  From the usual results regarding the [Rayleigh quotient](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rayleigh_quotient), we have
$$
\lambda_{min}(M) = \min_{\|x\| = 1} x^TMx \\
\lambda_{max}(M) = \max_{\|x\| = 1} x^TMx
$$
For arbitrary matrices, we have
$$
\|A\| = \max_{\|x\| = 1}\|Ax\|= \sqrt{\max_{\|x\| = 1} x^TA^TAx}
$$
So, for symmetric $M$, we have
$$
\|M\| = \sqrt{\max_{\|x\| = 1} x^TM^2x} = \sqrt{\lambda_{max}(M^2)}
$$
Note, however, that the eigenvalues of $M^2$ are simply $\lambda^2$ for all eigenvalues $\lambda$ of $M$.  Thus, we have
$$
\|M\| = \sqrt{\lambda_{max}(M^2)} = \max\{|\lambda|: \lambda \text{ is an eigenvalue of } M\} = \max_{\|x\| = 1} \left|x^TMx \right|
$$

Comment: See my latest edit